# SolrJ - Can't commit updates when authentication plugin is enabled

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, solrcloud

With `Solr 6.3.0`, in cloud mode, and 3 external `zookeepers` as cluster, and use `solrJ` as client.

### **A: Without authentication**

Before enabling `authentication`, I use following code to add/update document:

```
    CloudSolrClient client = cloudClientBuilder.build();
    UpdateResponse resp = client.add(doc, 5000);
    client.commit();
    client.close();
    return resp;
```

It works well, the new document is in searching result immediately.

### **B: With authentication enabled**

Then I enabled `basic authentication plugin` and `rule-based authorization plugin` (and `SSL` if that matters).

In order to set **credential** information, the code is refactored as following:

```
    // create request,
    UpdateRequest req = new UpdateRequest();

    // add doc to request,
    req.add(doc, 5000);

    // set credential,
    req.setBasicAuthCredentials(user, password);

    // create client,
    CloudSolrClient client = cloudClientBuilder.build();
    client.setDefaultCollection(ConfigUtil.getProp(ConfigUtil.KEY_SOLR_CORE));
    // do request & get response,
    UpdateResponse resp = req.process(client);

    client.commit();
    client.close();
```

Then it will get error similar as this:

> Error 401 require authentication, require authentication.

When debugging, the error occurs at line `client.commit();`.

---

**Try with curl**

I use `curl` to make an update:

> curl -k --user solr:password "https://localhost:8983/solr/corexxx/update?wt=json&indent=true&commit=true" -d '[{"id":"20041", "name":"xxx 41", "location":"xxx", "description":"xxx"}]'

It committed successfully ! And, the updates are visible in searching result immediately.

---

**My guess**

Since `curl` works well, I guess solr cloud itself works fine.

Thus the issue is due to the code from **B** which is based on SolrJ.

---

**Questions:**

- Why code **B** get `HTTP 401` error? How can I fix it?
- Could I use code from **A**, and still able to provide credential information,if yes, then how?

Thanks.

Comment: hey @Eric, i'm also facing this issue ,have you got any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You should change `client.commit()` for `req.commit(client, ConfigUtil.getProp(ConfigUtil.KEY_SOLR_CORE))`, the credentials are setted in the UpdateRequest.

Comment: I changed the line, the issue remains the same.

Comment: Look at this: [link](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/How-to-set-credentials-when-querying-using-SolrJ-Basic-Authentication-td4289909.html), I just replaced SolrRequest for UpdateRequest with docs, it worked for me.

Comment: I don't get it very clearly. Can you post a sample code? The link from above comment is for query, not for update, thx.

Answer (score 0):

It worked like this:

```
        SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();
        UpdateRequest up = new UpdateRequest();
        up.setBasicAuthCredentials(user, pass);
        up.add(doc1);
        up.process(client, core);
        up.commit(client, core);
        client.close();
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be a separate answer from [your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44501428/1575353)? If not, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44501428/edit) your other answer to contain this information.

Comment: The error remains the same: `Error 401 require authentication`.